# Arraylist with empty list fails to load message

Tags: android

The code populates the listview with items using baseadapter. To show the emptylist message, I am handling the emptylist using setEmptyView. But it fails with the IndexOutOfBoundsException. What i am doing wrong?

In Activity

```
ArrayList<String> fNameTemp = (ArrayList<String>) intent.getSerializableExtra("fName_Array");
ArrayList<String> lNameTemp = (ArrayList<String>) intent.getSerializableExtra("lName_Array");

MyListAdapter myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter SecondActivity.this,fNameTemp ,lNameTemp );
namesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_names);

namesList.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.emptyElement));
namesList.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
```

In xml

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_names"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >      
</ListView>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyElement"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="EMPTY!"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

Adapter

```
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<String> fName = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> lName = new ArrayList<String>();

    public MyListAdapter (Context c, ArrayList<String> LS_fName , ArrayList<String> LS_lName {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);

        this.fName = LS_fName;
        this.lName = LS_lName;
    }
public int getCount() {
        return fName.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return fName.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

static class ViewHolder {
        TextView value_fName;
        TextView value_lName;
            }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_names, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.value_fName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.value_fName);
            holder.value_lName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.value_lName);

 convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.value_fName.setText(fName.get(position));
        holder.value_lName.setText(lName.get(position));
     return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: can you add error logs

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the inflated `view` only referencing will not work.

```
namesList.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.emptyElement));
```

---

Example

```
       // Create a progress bar to display while the list loads
        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
        progressBar.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER));
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        namesList.setEmptyView(progressBar);
```